Conjecture: If $n\geq 2$ and a prime $p$ (equivalently, any integer $p>1$) divides $2^n-1,$ then $\gcd(p-1,n)>1.$

(Disproven) Conjecture: If a prime $p$ divides $2^n-1,$ then either $p=2^j\pm 1,\quad$
$n\mid p-1,\quad $ or $p-1\mid n.$

Unfortunately, this is false: the first counter-example is $2^{27} - 1 =(7)(73)(262657),$ because $n=27,p=73$ fails all three conditions.
However, I cannot find a counter-example to the following broader statement, whose truth I am interested in:

Conjecture: If $n\geq 2$ and a prime $p$ (equivalently*, any integer $p>1$) divides $2^n-1,$ then
$\gcd(p-1,n)>1.$

[* I was incorrect: it is not equivalent to consider $p$ not prime, and Vincent gives us a counter-example in his answer].
For example, $2^{35}-1 = (31)(71)(127)(122921),$ and $\gcd(35,30)>1,\ \gcd(35,70)>1,\ \gcd(35,126)>1,\ \gcd(35,122920)>1.$
The conjecture is trivially true for even $n.$ However, I have no idea how to approach the problem for odd $n.$
Because technically speaking the contrapositive of conjecture is convoluted, I think that (although I'm not certain) the part of the contrapositive that is equivalently interesting is:

Conjecture: If $n\geq 2$ and $\gcd(m-1,n)=1,$ then $m\not\mid2^n-1.$

Results from this question are possibly useful. I guess Fermat's Little Theorem could also be useful.

For your last conjecture, take $n=33$ and $m=161$, for example.

As here in dupe $!\bmod p!:\ 2^n \equiv 1 \equiv 2^{p-1} \Rightarrow\ 2^{(n,p-1)} \equiv  1,,$ so $(n,p!-!1)>\color{#c00}{\bf 1},$ (else $,p\mid 2^{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}!-!1 = 1\ \ $

We can use the concept of multiplicative order. Since $2^n\equiv 1\pmod p$ and $2^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$, we have $\mathrm{ord}_p(2)\mid\gcd(p-1,n)$. But the order cannot be 1, so $\gcd(p-1,n)>1$.
Writing this in words, we have that the following stronger statement is true:

Let $k$ be the smallest positive integer satisfying $p\mid 2^k-1$ for a given prime $p$. If $p\mid 2^n-1$ for some positive integer $n$, then $k\mid \gcd(p-1,n)$.


So I think it is to do with Lagrange's Theorem.

Yes, the fact that $\textrm{ord}_p(2)$ (the number I call $a$ in my answer) divides $p-1$ is a special case of Lagrange's theorem that the order of an element divides the order of the group. The group we are talking about is the multiplicative group of residue classes mod $p$ that have a multiplicative inverse mod $p$. For $p$ prime these are all non-zero classes and the order of the group is $p - 1$. In general it is $\phi(p)$, this is the definition of $\phi$.

Yes this is true for $p$ prime. (It is not so obvious to me that this implies the case that $p$ is any integer.)
We need the following lemma:

Let $a$ be the smallest positive integer such that $2^a \equiv 1 \mod p$ . Then $a$ divides every $b$ such that $2^b \equiv 1 \mod p$

This is fairly easy to prove using division of $b$ by $a$ with remainder.
Now we have $a|n$ because by definition of $n$ we have that $2^n \equiv 1 \mod p$.
And we have $a|(p-1)$ because $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p$ by Fermat's little theorem.
So $a$ is a common divisor of $n$ and $p - 1$, and it remains to show that $a > 1$. But by definition of $a$ this is just the statement that $2 \neq 1 \mod p$ which is true for every prime $p$ by virtue of $p \geq 2$.
EDIT: when $p$ is any integer $\geq 2$ but not necessarily prime, the same reasoning (replacing Fermat's little theorem with Euler's generalization of it) implies that $\gcd(n, \phi(p)) > 1$ with $\phi$ the Euler-phi-function. For prime $p$ we have that $\phi(p) = p - 1$.
For composite $p$, the number $\phi(p)$ can be considerably smaller than $p - 1$ and it also need not be a divisor of $p-1$, so there might be counterexamples with composite $p$ to the original conjecture. I will try to find out if there are indeed any.
FURTHER EDIT: the original post already provides a counterexample to the compositie-$p$-case! Take $n = 35$ and $p = 31*127$. Then $p - 1 = 3936$ which is divisible by neither $5$ nor $7$.
